Children's non-fiction book: invention of toothbrush, zippers, bubble gum, paperclip, spoonerisms, Nostradamus, Otis elevators, reincarnation
I'm trying to find a book from my childhood. I was born in 1993 and the book was already quite old, so maybe it was released in the 1980's, perhaps late 70's
The paper was newspaper consistency and had comic style black and white, cartoony illustrations. The pages were very yellowed, almost brown. It wrote whimsical non-fictional accounts about interesting things such as scrimshaw, the invention of toothbrush using bones and bristles, history of Valentine’s Day, invention of bubble gum and the zipper, and reincarnation, Nostradamus predictions. I also remember another one about different types of bananas and how in some countries, people eat green bananas. The tone was humorous, perhaps whimsical, and childlike. Lots of exclamations in the articles and the illustrations speech and thought bubbles.
I've seen other posts referencing it, but it's never been solved. Other posts included:

Each factoid either took up a page, or two side-by-side pages, and would have nothing to do with previous factoids (i.e. One minute the topic was hybrid plants and trees, the next minute the discussion is focused on plane black boxes, or the king of New York)


One about doctor spooner, after whom spoonerisms were named
One about The Great Siberian Explosion
One about Toothbrushes, maybe being invented in jail?
One about the guy who invented the paperclip, and sold the patent for $400
One about Otis and his elevators
Plane black boxes
an illustration of a monk using a candle as an alarm clock, sleepily saying 5 more minutes
a discussion on the history of the Hope Diamond
a discussion on Louis XVI and Marie Antoinette, including a cartoon drawing of them being beheaded, with Marie angry or upset at Louis XVI for something
the history of writing, or something to that effect, complete with a drawing of a what looked like a bearskin rug being written on, all the while the pelt laughing, saying it was ticklish.
I really don't know how else to describe the book. It was very zany and wacky, but also entertaining. If you would look at it from the cover, you wouldn't think it was very child-like in nature, since if I recall it properly, the cover featured more lifelike pictures, including a knight on a horse, wielding a lance. I've been meaning to at least know its title again.

MY copy had the cover torn off, so I can't corroborate what this other poster said about the knight on a horse.
I've been desperately trying to find it for years. Any help would be so appreciated!

Was the book "international", or quite specific to a country? In what language did you read the book? I am aware that it might have been a translation. but these details could help.

It looks like it was solved on Reddit: "A Treasury of Amazing Knowledge" by Susan Lurie.

"quite old" - just 5 years old at that point. More proof human memories are awful at the details.

According to Reddit user jorgemckinky (and confirmed by a user who most likely also posted this question on SE), this is "A Treasury of Amazing Knowledge" (1988) by Susan Lurie. From Goodreads:

Our spectacular world is a treasury of exciting ideas, miraculous discoveries, awesome inventions, and natural wonders. Explore the secrets of dreams, the origin of buttons, animal-eating plants, strange climates, and shooting stars. Read about vivid rainbows, learn about superstitions, journey to far-away places, and travel back in time to the visions of Nostradamus.
All these facts and much more are all here in this marvelous collection--A Treasury of Amazing Knowledge.

